# How do i handle the timezones for every relayed message

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, chat

I am creating a web chat application using asp.net vb. I have got the chat system to work as messages are sent and relayed back to the clients. But there was something i noticed but never thought it would be a problem. I am from England and the chat application is sitting on servers in America and noticed when the message displayed the time, the times were situated in American time zones. How would i go about setting the timezones that will correspond to there country timezones.

So if the message display 17:00 American time, then the message sent to England should display 12:00 English time.

All messages are stored in SQL Server Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would store all the times in the database as GMT Then on your local application you can adjust the time you display to the user based on the local timezone.

Im not sure if you can use the culture info or anything like that to automatically convert the time to the correct timezone, but you can easily add or subtract the hours yourself.

Comment: +1 : UTC is a bit more common, but the principle is the same.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time